# jquery detect when user scrolled to the top of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have dynamical list

```
<div id="content" class="content" data-role="content" data-scroll="y">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <form>
            <ul id="myList" data-role="listview">
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to append another list to `myList`, when you scrolled it to the top;
How can I detect when user scrolled it to the top?

I tried some variants of `scrollTop` function, like:

```
  $(window).bind('scrollstop', function(){
    alert("1 "+$(window).scrollTop());  
    alert("2 "+$('#content').scrollTop()); 
    alert("3 "+$('#myDiv').scrollTop()); 
    alert("4 "+$('#myList').scrollTop()); 
    alert("5 "+$('#myList li').scrollTop()); 
});
```

but all of them returned `0` :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `scroll` event to the element being scrolled. Assuming you are scrolling the `#content` element this will work:

```
$('#content').on('scroll', function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        alert('at the top');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ga22S/)